# Multiple Arguments in AlamoFire.Request

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to access Spotify's web API. I am currently using Alamofire to request the search operation which only requires a token. However, I could not figure out why it won't let me send multiple arguments.

```
let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer {your access token}"]
var searchURL = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Odesza&type=track"

AF.request(.GET, url, headers: headers)
    .responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alamofire does a great job of formatting parameters to a request url. Just as you pass parameters with the .post method to the AF request function you also pass a parameters [string : any] to the AF request for .get methods as well. The difference is .post will put the parameters in the request.body/data vs. .get will format the parameters into the url with the ?q=my_search_string

something along the lines of this:

Let params: [string :any] = ["q": "odesza", "type":"track"]
AF.request(.GET, url, parameters:params, headers: headers) .responseJSON { response in debugPrint(response

Comment: So I changed the format of the request to AF.request(url,method: .get, parameters:params)
            .responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
        }    this allows me to run the code, however it doesnt work since i dont have my header in there. When i add my header to AF.request(url,method: .get, parameters:params, headers:headers) it goes back to Extra argument 'method' in call.

Comment: the following is working for me,  i have wrapper API client class but this the alamofire request line:     Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: method, parameters: params, encoding: encoding, headers: header)

Comment: Did you have to import something to have the client class available? Its not coming up for my classes.

Comment: what is the current error your seeing? via pods the Alamofire.request function is defined as :                                                                                                           
public func request(
    _ url: URLConvertible,
    method: HTTPMethod = .get,
    parameters: Parameters? = nil,
    encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
    headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil)
    -> DataRequest
{

Comment: Extra argument 'method' in call and this is still with AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters:params,headers:headers). I have also tried AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters:params,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:headers) and i get the same error also.... I have tried changing the encoding to encode since there is also another function with AF defined that way and I wasnt sure. Could this error be bigger then just the actual code? I have alamofire 5.0 and xcode 10.1

Comment: Figured out it was the header that was messing it up.... changed it to  AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters:params, headers:["Authorization": "Bearer "+header]) and it worked out. (header is just the token). Thank you for the help!

Comment: no problem glad you figured it out, I've ran into that problem before so I know your pain ;) Happy Coding!